# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Tags: asp.net, security

Currently I'm facing a security issue when authenticating a user with builtin asp.net membership provider.

The issue is : I authenticate with user AAA and after, I do the same with user BBB on different computer. When authenticating user BBB and calling

**HttpContext.Current.User.Identity**

on AAA's computer, it will return BBB's credential. Here is my code:

```
public void SignIn(string UserEmail, decimal UserProviderId, bool CreatePersistentCookie) 
{ 
    string userName = ""; 
    bool validUser = _acctMembership.ValidateUser(UserEmail, UserProviderId, out userName, out _userId);
    if (validUser) 
    {
        string name = userName + ";" + UserEmail; _formAuth.SignIn(name, CreatePersistentCookie);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException("Invalid Email or Password");
    }
}
```

Conclusion:

The last logged user overrides identity of the users logged before.

Could anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you show the code you use to login the user?

Comment: I do that : FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);   of course after validating the user input..

Comment: Some code still would be helpful.

Comment: @VadimVisnevschi Please edit (=update) your question with your code.

Comment: Without seeing any code the only think I can suggest is clear cookie cache on boot machines and see what happens.

Comment: So in my code there is nothing complicated. After validating user input, i set an Auth ticket and after, i call HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name. It works fine until I authenticate the second user on a different computer, which seems to override the name of the first logged one. Thank you

Comment: As suggested @AliK, i've tried to clear cache by adding in RegisterGlobalFilters the code : OutputCacheAttribute filterCache = new OutputCacheAttribute();
            filterCache.Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Client;
            filterCache.Duration = 0;
            filterCache.NoStore = true;
            filterCache.VaryByParam = "none";
            filters.Add(filterCache);  but it didn't work either

Comment: Or maybe I was doing something wrong in the code for clearing the cache.. could you suggest a better approach?

Comment: Show the code that validates the credentials and sets the cookie.

Comment: `public void SignIn(string UserEmail, decimal UserProviderId, bool CreatePersistentCookie)
        {
            string userName = "";
            bool validUser = _acctMembership.ValidateUser(UserEmail, UserProviderId, out userName, out _userId);

            if (validUser)
            {
                string name = userName + ";" + UserEmail;
                _formAuth.SignIn(name, CreatePersistentCookie);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException("Invalid Email or Password");
            }
        }`

Comment: Ah you actually posted some code.  Right now, it seems you are using email as the username.  When you call SignIn(name, just use userName instead of name.

Comment: Yes, this code I use for the external users(like Google, Facebook..) and I don't see a problem using whatever for identification of user..

Comment: do you log into AAAA and BBBB with the same email address ?

Comment: Not at all, there are 2 different emails on different computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are validating a user with **UserEmail**, but create **FormAuhtenicationTicket** with some other value called **name**.

```
bool validUser = _acctMembership.ValidateUser(XXXXX, UserProviderId, out userName, out _userId);
if (validUser) 
{
   string name = userName + ";" + UserEmail; 
   _formAuth.SignIn(XXXXX, CreatePersistentCookie);
}
```

XXXXX in the above code must be same.

Comment: So i still don't see a problem of storing in the cookie 'userName + ";" + UserEmail' and retrieving it later. These values would be unique. Even if I use your example above, I get the same issue. And one more thing, I do custom validation. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, so I figured it out. It was my bad. Sorry for bugging you guys. I appreciate your efforts, it indicated me where to look for the problem.

Comment: @VadimVisnevschi If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as **Anwser**. Or if it's totally different from my answer, you can create a new answer, and mark it as **Answer**. *Either way will help others who look for the same answer.*